# Couldn't resolve host 'maps.googleapis.com issue occurs randomly in google reverse geocoding

Tags: php, google-maps, google-api

i tried Google reverse geocoding using PHP. If i run my PHP for first time it returns formatted address perfectly, again i reload the PHP means it returns , `Curl error: Couldn't resolve host 'maps.googleapis.com'`

If i again run that PHP it return address properly...That means it works randomly....

I search about this error, all said it DNS Problem, so contact DNS provider...But they said there is no problem in their side...

I tried time delay(sleep function) in between queries upto 60 seconds..but that also not works same error occurs after 60 sec delay....

**My PHP Code:**

```
<?php
    //sleep(60);
    $url='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=11.49731013,77.24445245&sensor=false';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.mysite.com/dns.php');
    $body = curl_exec($ch);

    if($body=== false) {
        echo "<br>";
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
        echo "<br>";
        }
        else
        {
        $json = json_decode($body);
        $addr2=$json->results[0]->formatted_address;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $addr2;
        echo "<br>";
        }
?>
```

is it any problem in my coding....please help me solve this problem...

Answer (score 0):

You could just add maps.googleapis.com to your server's hosts file, or, if you don't have access to that, connect to the IP address the address resolves to instead.  Even another way would be to cache the IP address that maps.googleapis.com resolves to, and then use that cached IP address to connect in the event you get a timeout from using the FQDN.